# Rest API call using Azure Web Jobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service

I have implemented Rest API call using HttpTrigger based Azure functions, now customer has asked to implement the same using Azure Web Jobs instead of Azure Functions (owing to cost).

Are there any options available, please provide some reference how to achieve it in Azure web jobs

Thanks! in advance

Answer (score 4):

No, that is not what WebJobs are for. You might be lookin into building an ASP.NET Web API and hosting it in an App Service Plan.

> WebJobs is a feature of Azure App Service that enables you to run a program or script in the same context as a web app, API app, or mobile app. There is no additional cost to use WebJobs.

Taken from [Run **Background tasks** with WebJobs in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create)

Also, WebJobs do **NOT** support the HttpTrigger. The triggers that *are* supported by WebJobs:

- Timer
- Azure Storage queues and blobs
- Azure Service Bus queues and topics
- Azure Cosmos DB
- Azure Event Hubs
- File system

Source: [What are Microsoft Flow, Logic Apps, Functions, and WebJobs? - Comparison table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs#comparison-table)

**EDIT:**
As far as your solution goes: Either run it in a Function or in an App Service. If it's just one HttpTriggered call and (minor) startup times after some inactivity of the API aren't an issue: go for the Function implementation.

When retrieving a 'huge amount' of records (what is a huge amount?), as long as your Functions don't have any state and you pass in all information to determine the records to receive, there shouldn't be any issues. The Function app timeout duration in a consumption plan is 5 minutes by default.

Comment: Webjobs was new to me and i was not aware of its features, thanks for your comments ,so from your view point implementing Rest API using Azure function is the best possible design?

Comment: Either run it in a Function or in an App Service. If it's just one HttpTriggered call and (minor) startup times after some inactivity aren't an issue: go for the Function implementation.

Comment: One more query i have if im trying to retrieve huge amount of records from Rest API with proper page size defined do u think there will be any timeout issue with the function implementation...

Comment: What is a "huge amount of records"? Generally, as long as your Functions don't have any state and you pass in all information to determine the records to receive, there shouldn't be any issues. (A Function in a consumption plan is killed after 5 minutes by default)